# how to count the number of files an extension was just added to?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so I just added the extension .txt to all files in a directory, I want to go beyond that and now count the number of files whose extension I just changed. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To know the number of .txt files, you can simply do `ls | grep '.txt$' | wc -l`

To know the number of file you change, you need to either count them while you change the extension, or count the number before, the number after, and substract them.

This last method can be done like this:

```
oldnum="$(ls | grep '.txt$' | wc -l)"
# Do the rename here
newnum="$(ls | grep '.txt$' | wc -l)"
result=$((newnum - oldnum)) # $result now hold the number of renamed files
```

Comment: How about `ls *.txt | wc -l` for extra brevity?

Comment: The robust version would be `arr=(*.txt); echo ${#arr[@]}` - can deal with any special characters in filenames.

Comment: This would work differently if there is a .txt directory (because ls would proceed to list the content of that directory)

Comment: would this count only the .txt extensions that were just changed though? not the ones already existing?

Comment: If this is a one off thing, you may use `ls -lc`, find out the time you did the rename, and grep for it to before `wc`

Comment: from a script is there anyway to code this? I'm trying to run the file and have it tell me the number of new .txt files just renamed?

Comment: @Khoyo : Your solution would fail for instance, if the rename consists of the actions `mv foo.abc foo.txt; mv bar.txt bar.abc`. In this case, the difference calculated according to your algorithm would be zero, even though we have a new .txt file.

Comment: This is true, but then the only reliable option is to count the number of file changed during the rename.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you didn't forget an hour when you had modified files.

For example, if you have modified files 1 hour ago, just run in working directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*\.txt' -cmin -65
```

This code will print all the files with *.txt name who were modified less than 65 minutes ago.

Comment: This was not what the OP asked. The point is not when the **content** of the file was changed, but when the **name** has changed. You won't see this from the mtime.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 you are right. Edited my answer.

Comment: I fear that the updated answer isn't correct either. First, I'm not sure whether a name change is considered as status change (I can't reproduce it, but I'm having here only Cygwin, not a real Linux). More importantly, it would reveal **any** status change, not only the fact that it was renamed to *.txt.